# Custom left join with magic rails getter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, left-join, rails-activerecord

How can I use this kind of query with rails ?

```
Question.joins("left join answers a on a.question_id = questions.id and a.user_id = #{current_user.id}").select('questions.*, a.*')
```

I would like then to use question.answer or some of magic getter.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your query with JOIN to query with subquery:

```
answers = Answer.where(user_id: current_user.id)
questions = Question.where(id: answers.select(:question_id))
```

In this case you can use your `Question` object and all its associations:

```
questions.each do |question|
  p question.answer
  ...
```

Comment: Your answer is more like inner join but not left.

Comment: Right. In this case you can add OR condition for select Question object without answers or write additional AR query for select such questions.